# How to get the angular component class reference inside an emitted Highcharts selection event callback function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I guess this is a general javascript closure related problem but I am going to use specific example as I cannot wrap my head around it thinking angular-way.

I have an angular component which is using Highcharts library to display a chart. Highcharts can emit event when user selects part of the chart by mouse dragging. The event provides a callback function which takes 2 arguments e.g- `function(chartRef, event)`. I have provided the reference of a class method to the callback function. When the event is emitted by highcharts, inside the method `this` is bound to the chartRef (callback function scope) and not the angular component class (`AppComponent`) itself. How can I get a hold of the angular component class instead so that I can use the returned values by the event to my angular application?

```
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts'

export class AppComponent {
  @Output() selection = new EventEmitter<any>()

  chart: Chart;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    let chart = new Chart({
      chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        events: {
          selection: this.onChartSelectionEvent,
        },
    },
    // code removed for brevity
    this.chart = chart
    )
  }

  onChartSelectionEvent(chartRef, event) {
    console.log(chartRef.xAxis[0].min) // logs correctly
    console.log(chartRef.xAxis[0].max) // logs correctly
    this.selection.next(chartRef.xAxis[0].max) // doesn't work
    // ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
    // because `this` refers to the chartRef, not the angular class
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz for the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ks4ueq)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) to store a component reference:

```
onChartSelectionEvent = (function(self) {
    console.log(self)
    return function(chartRef: any, chartEvent:any){
    console.log(chartRef.xAxis[0].min)
    console.log(chartRef.xAxis[0].max)
    console.log(self)
    }
    // `this` is bound to the chartRef that is emmited by the Highcharts event
    // How can I get a hold of the angular component class (AppComponent) instead?
    //this.selection.next(chartRef.xAxis[0].max)
})(this)
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqzyjv?file=src/app/app.component.ts